# "From the above analysis, we can see that" VS "From the analysis above, we can see that"

Tags: syntactic-analysis

What is the difference between this two sentences?
I looked into the google,and found that these two sentences are used.

Comment: The first sounds more refined.  Otherwise, equivalent to my mind.

Comment: While I got from one native speaker that probably the second pattern is more formal than the first. I am a little confused.

Answer (score 0):

Both forms are correct and mean the same thing.

The adjective "above" can be used as a post-positive adjective. In some cases post-positive adjectives can vary the meaning of the sentence, but not in this case.

> ...above analysis... : normal adjective use
>
> ...analysis above... : post-positive adjective

In general, post-positive adjectives are rarer, and can signify archaic use. The post-positive adjective use looks more formal to many (due to the archaic nature / rarity of the construction in general), so I've seen it used commonly in formal contexts.

Edited: Thanks to Edwin pointing this out, I did a bit more research on how common each construction is. What I found is that until the 1990s "the above item" was more common than "the item above", but recently the latter construction has become more common [[Link]](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20item%20above,the%20above%20item&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,the%20item%20above;,c0;.t1;,the%20above%20item;,c0). However, the use of "the below item" seems to be negligible compared to "the item below" [[Link]](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20item%20below,the%20below%20item&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,the%20item%20below;,c0)

Comment: I don't agree that 'the below N' is common usage.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Good point. I've definitely seen it around, but thinking about, it is not common.

Comment: There's a previous analysis at the linked duplicate thread (above)(!)

Comment: Thanks! Didn't see your latest before going some research of my own :)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: 'the below N' sounds awkward but is becoming more popular.

Comment: @Mitch I agree, but I'd not agree it's common usage yet.

Comment: Using "item" in your NGram links isn't very illuminating, because it's not all that common in OP's context. If we check [the actual word "analysis"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+analysis+above%2Cthe+above+analysis&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20analysis%20above%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20above%20analysis%3B%2Cc0) we see **above** almost always comes first (same for "example", but not quite so strongly). But these are somewhat specialised contexts - adjectival and adverbial *above/below* are usually post-positioned.

Comment: Many thanks to the friends above. It seems that "the analysis above" is becoming more and more popular than "the above annalysis" does. In the meantime, probably "the analysis below" is formal while "the below analysis" is seldom accepted. Right?